# Using jQuery plugin within directive $(window).load

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, twentytwenty

At the moment I'm trying to use this plugin https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty within a AngularJS Directive.

When I load my application for the first time everything works fine, but since the plugin runs after `$(window).load` and my app is a SPA it executes only once. That means when I leave the view and come back at a later point, the plugin stops working.

My Directive looks like this:

```
.directive('ngCompare', function() {
return {
  cache: false,
  restrict: 'A',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    img1: '=',
    img2: '='
  },
  template: "<div id='container1'>" +
  "<img ng-src='{{img1}}'>" +
  "<img ng-src='{{img2}}'>" +
  "</div>",
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $(window).load(function(){
      $(element).twentytwenty();
    });
  }
}
})
```

I'm still learning AngularJS and this is my first time using a jQuery plugin within a Directive, so I have absolutely no idea how to solve this. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place it on `element.load` & `$window.load` both, so it will fire every time when element gets rendered & window gets loaded.

You need to set `element.on('load')` event from the `$window.load` event, so it will ensure the event will fire once only at starting kick of directive

**Directive**

```
.directive('ngCompare',['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        cache: false,
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            img1: '=',
            img2: '='
        },
        template: "<div id='container1'>" +
            "<img ng-src='{{img1}}'>" +
            "<img ng-src='{{img2}}'>" +
            "</div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var setElementLoadEvent = funcion() {
                element.on('load', function() {
                    element.twentytwenty();
                });
            };
            $window.load(function() {
                element.twentytwenty();
                setElementLoadEvent();
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried your code and it still won't work because the `$(window).load` is only called at the start of the app and not when you return to a view you've already been on.

Comment: @KevinSleegers `element.on('load' ` gets called or not?

Comment: no it doesn't. I've added a `console.log('test')` within the `element.on('load')` but that doesn't appear in the console.

Comment: are you loading `ngCompare` only once or multiple times?

Comment: It's used only once on a template (.html) page.

Comment: @KevinSleegers that means you are loading it once only and showing hiding that element only..Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. 
For your information, the `img1` and `img2` attributes are dynamic, based on the route params.

Comment: cooll so you can need to put watch on those `img1` & `img2` will do the trick for you..in that watch you need to fire your `twentytwenty()` method on element

Comment: Awesome! I've added a `scope.$watchGroup` to watch `img1` and `img2`, and it works fine now! Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: It is still working fine whenever I use `grunt serve` to run my application. But when I build my app using `grunt build` and afterwards run `grunt serve:dist` the directive stops working completely. The html code of the template is not being replaced by the plugin's specific html. All my other directives and plugins do still work. Also, no errors appear in my console.log. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: There might be a below problem.

1.are you using minification? that may be one of the problem.

2. do clear browser cache an check the functinality.

3.open developer tool.goto source tab check.wheather latest file has been loaded in browser or not.

Comment: Yes, all of my .js files are getting minified. I will get back to you to answer your other questions when I am at my office in about an hour.

Comment: @KevinSleegers take a look at my edit..you should alway follow DI array annotation when doing js minification

Comment: @KevinSleegers did you found any issue with those 3 points which i suggested above..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76860/discussion-between-kevin-sleegers-and-pankajparkar).